# Combining html and php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hey I am trying to display the term name as a link inside my wordpress template.

I have tried to close the php tag and use quotation marks to end the html and begin with php. But as soon as I want to display the term name, I get an error message.

```
echo   '<li><a href="https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/page-" . $term->name . '">'$term->name'</a></li>';
```

I thought this code should display the term names and direct to its link.

Comment: Just do the same concatenation for the last variable too:  
echo   '<li><a href="https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/page-" . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';

Comment: Doing the same concatenation does not give me an error message anymore, but there is also no link to click on.

Comment: That probably means $term->name is empty. Try dumping out $term with print_r($term) to see what's in it. Maybe the property you're looking for has a different name.

Answer (score 0):

there is some typo in your code.
try following code

```
echo   '<li><a href="https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/page-' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
```